# GCC automatically grouping variable and code sections

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linker

My linux C project has a simple makefile which compiles and links several modules.

I can see in the output.map that variables and functions are being linked on an as they are declared basis, module by module.

I would like to have all variables from all modules grouped together in one section, and all functions grouped together in another.

I know I can do this by defining sections, but I can't help wondering if there is a ready made linker switch that will do this automatically.

Answer (score 0):

by using a 'linker command' file, you can place everything exactly as you would like it.

However, with `gcc`, there are several sections automatically defined.

The .text section has all the executable code
The .data section has all the pre-defined data
The .bss section has all the variables

There are a few other sections, mostly for special purposes

The above is a somewhat simplified overview, however, data and code will NOT be strung together as you indicate.  Amongst other reasons because variables and code require different parameters for the memory pages.